# php - доступ к вложенным элементам массива

Tags: php, массивы

Есть многомерный массив.

Нужно написать функцию которая будет выводить нужный элемент по цепочке ключей с разделителем.

Примерно вот так:

```
// точка в качестве разделителя
$result = get_array_el($array, 'level.level_2.level_3.level_N')


function get_array_el($array, $key_string, $default = null){

    // точки нет - значит 1й уровень вложенности
    if(strpos($key, '.') === false){
        return isset($array[$key_string]) ? $array[$key_string] : $default; 
    }

    // получаем все уровни 
    $levels = explode('.', $key_string);


    // и тут нужно как то так.
    // но я не могу придумать как
    return $array[$levels[0]][$levels[1]][$levels[2]][$levels[N]]

}
```

---

Вот что получилось.
Конечно хотелось универсального решения. 
Но в моем случае хватит 3-х уровней вложенности.

```
function get_array_el($array, $key_string, $default = null){

    // точки нет - значит 1й уровень вложенности
    if(strpos($key, '.') === false){
        return isset($array[$key_string]) ? $array[$key_string] : $default; 
    }


    // получаем все уровни 
    $lvl = explode('.', $key_string);

    // вложенность 2
    if (count($lvl) == 2) {
        return isset($array[$lvl[0]][$lvl[1]]) ? $array[$lvl[0]][$lvl[1]] : $default;
    }

    // вложенность 3
    elseif (count($lvl) == 3) {
        return isset($array[$lvl[0]][$lvl[1]][$lvl[2]]) ? $array[$lvl[0]][$lvl[1]][$lvl[2]] : $default;
    }

    return $default;
}
```